# Use JQuery SlideToggle Without Moving Content Below

Tags: javascript, jquery, slidetoggle

I have two DIVs that need to occupy the same space on the page.  The back DIV has some form elements and I am allowing the user to slide the front DIV in order to access the back DIV.

The problem is, the content below the front DIV is moving up on top of the back DIV.  How can I fix this?

Here is an example of what I am doing now.

http://jsfiddle.net/7DFfa/3/

Thanks
Sheridan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the height of your wrapper:

```
$("#wrapper").height($("#front").height());
```

When you "slideUp" your `#front` div, your `#wrapper` div is losing its height.

See it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/7DFfa/4/

You'll also need to toggle the `z-index` of your `#back` div so that the form elements can be accessed: http://jsfiddle.net/7DFfa/5/

```
$("#opener").toggle(function() {
    $("#front").stop().slideToggle(function() {
        $("#back").css("z-index", "1");
    });

    $(this).text("Show Front");
    }, function() {

    $("#back").css("z-index", "-1");
    $("#front").stop().slideToggle();

    $(this).text("Show Back")
});​
```

Alternatively, you could toggle both divs: http://jsfiddle.net/7DFfa/7/

```
$("#back").hide();
$("#wrapper, #back").height($("#front").height());

$("#opener").toggle(function() {
    $("#front").stop().slideToggle();
    $("#back").stop().slideToggle();
    $(this).text("Show Front");
    }, function() {
    $("#front").stop().slideToggle();
    $("#back").stop().slideToggle();
    $(this).text("Show Back")
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Try add height to wrapper div

```
<div id="wrapper" style="width:400px;height:140px;">
```

The first div expand thanks to `</br>` but the second div doesn't contain any "expandable" tags, so its height less.

Answer (score 0):

Adding height to the wrapper div is one option. Another one is setting absolute positioning for the button and adding a top for it equal to the wrapper height. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7DFfa/6/)